# MATLAB n-back test

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I am trying to find a n-back (also known as 1-back/one-back) test made in MATLAB.
In case you know how to make one (for instance by using psychtoolbox) or have some code you would like to share, that would be very appreciated.

Basically anything that could help me is appreciated, as long as it is connected to MATLAB.

Comment: google suggests this: https://github.com/nickpenaranda/Multi-N-Back any good?